# Laravel Mcamara\LaravelLocalization giving error when used in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

I just installed Mcamara\LaravelLocalization following the documentation but I get an error `Call to undefined method Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::setLocale()`

The error comes from the web.php routes file of my package. If I use the same code in my main routes file it works perfect. All other routes of my package work, only those I want to localize don't.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['web', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']], function() {
    Route::get('/{page}', 'FrontPagesController@index');
});
```

I found on stackoverflow that this could be because locale in `config/app.php` is not set but in my case it is set to `en`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: go under `app/config.php` and check if locale is set, `'locale' => 'en'`

Comment: it's `config/app.php` and it is set to en, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: This can mean that your library isnt loaded, have you added class path? and if you have done it, then try composer dumpautoload

Comment: I did. dup-autoload gives me this error

    `In Facade.php line 221:
    Call to undefined method Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::setLocale()                                                           
    Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and I just run `php artisan config:cache` in the terminal and I `restarted` my editor VS Code